# C: Regular expression optimization | Saving state

Tags: c, regex

Lets suppose i'd like to search through "AAAAAAAABBBBBBB" and "AAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC".
I search for a pattern "(AB|AC)".

Is there a way to saving the state of the search after searching the "AAAAAAAA" part and then continuing with the [B..] and [C..] part seperatly? so i need to search in [A..] only once.

i write a short pseudo code example to be more clear.

step one:

```
pattern = "(AB|AC)"
match("AAAAAAAA", pattern)
save_state()
```

step two:

```
match("BBBBBBB", pattern)
```

should the find match "AB"

step three:

```
restore_state()
match("CCCCCCCCCCC", pattern)
```

should find match "AC"

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. They are too different strings, in two different locations. How would saving the result of one help the other?

Comment: Do you mean `A(B|C)` or `A[BC]`?

Comment: no, the first x letters are the same (A). and if they are very large, i'd like to search through them only once. the saved state at the end of the A sequence would the be A. continuing with B... it would generate a match AB, the same for continuing a second time with the B-sequence...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you use the regex `A(B|C)` the regex engine is quite efficient about it -- it'll search for the "A" just once, and then check for a following B or C? Otherwise, you could search through for the "A" and save the index, and then continue searching for "B" and "C" from there, although this is less efficient than doing `A(B|C)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a regex flavor that uses a (real) NFA/DFA approach (like [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2)), you don't have to store something since every input character is (or should be) used only once (this could not get better).

If your flavor uses a backtracking algorithm, you might have luck. Some of these engines allow you to introduce a non-backtracking (aka possessive) part by using `(?>x)` or `x{1}+` (where `{1}` could be any quantifier)

So in your case, it could be (if it's allowed)

```
(?>A)(B|C)
```

or

```
A{1}+(B|C)
```